# Component Error: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-maps

I am building app using react native expo and google map api

I am getting this error

> ERROR  [Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `MapComponent`.]

MapComponent

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, StyleSheet, View,Image } from 'react-native'
import { mapStyle} from "../global/mapStyle"
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE,} from 'react-native-maps'; 
import { colors,parameters } from '../global/styles';
import {MapViewDirections} from 'react-native-maps-directions';
import {GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY} from "@env";

export default class MapComponent extends Component {

    constructor(){
      super()
        this.state ={

        }
      
        this._map = React.createRef(35)
    }
    
    componentDidUpdate(){
      setTimeout(()=>{
        if(this.props.userDestination.latitude !== null){
          this._map.current.fitToCoordinates(
            [this.props.userOrigin,this.props.userDestination],{
              edgePadding:{top:450,right:50,left:50,bottom:350},
              animated:true
            }
          )
        }
      },500)
   }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <MapView
                    provider ={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                    style = {styles.map}
                    customMapStyle ={mapStyle}
                    ref = {this._map}
                        >
                     { this.props.userOrigin.latitude != null &&   
                        <MapView.Marker  coordinate = {this.props.userOrigin} anchor = {{x:0.5,y:0.5}} >
                            <Image 
                                source ={require('../../assets/location.png')}
                                style ={styles.markerOrigin2}
                                resizeMode ="cover"
                            />
                        </MapView.Marker>
                     }
                     { this.props.userDestination.latitude != null &&   
                        <MapView.Marker coordinate = {this.props.userDestination} anchor = {{x:0.5,y:0.5}} >
                            <Image 
                                source ={require('../../assets/location.png')}
                                style ={styles.markerDestination}
                                resizeMode ="cover"
                            />
                        </MapView.Marker>
                     }
                    {this.props.userDestination.latitude !== null &&
                        <MapViewDirections 
                          origin={this.props.userOrigin}
                          destination={this.props.userDestination}
                          apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}
                          strokeWidth={4}
                          strokeColor={colors.black}
                        />
                    } 
                </MapView> 
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

where am I going wrong, kindly help

Comment: Your error specifically says this: `You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.` Have you checked this one?